# Package com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http does not exist

Tags: android, rx-java

I'll go direct to point. While I'm try to run the app I got some errors

```
package com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http does not exist

package com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json does not exist

package io.reactivex does not exist
```

build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev186-1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-java6', version: '1.23.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.oauth-client', name: 'google-oauth-client-jetty', version: '1.23.0'
    compile 'com.github.PierfrancescoSoffritti:AndroidYouTubePlayer:4.1.7'
    //compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha2"
    //compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha2"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Do I need to compile some library in the build.gradle? Let me know and thank's to all!

Comment: Are you using rxjava?

Comment: Yes i'm using rxjava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try :**

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.10'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
```

OR

```
compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:0.16.1'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
```

EDIT

```
compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-android', version: '1.22.0'
```

Comment: Ty for help me with the last i've solved the rxjava dependencies but i still got error

Comment: package com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http does not exist

package com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json does not exist

Comment: @Trusted Happy to help :) happy coding :)

Comment: @Trusted Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
compile group: 'com.google.http-client', name: 'google-http-client-android', version: '1.12.0-beta'
```

Click [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-android/1.12.0-beta)!
Select gradle.